# array comparison

Tags: arrays, postgresql

```
select preference.id from preference where  
--array(select id from date_etl where local_date >= '02/01/2011' and local_date <= '02/25/2011') && date_etl_array  --option 3 gives error, do not know why? and how to fix it?  
--array(select id from date_etl where local_date >= '02/01/2011' and local_date <= '02/25/2011') && '{1342715,1342739}'  --option 2 runs with no error  
--date_etl_array && '{1342715,1342739}'  --option 1 runs with no error

=#\d preference
date_etl_array              | integer[]                   |
```

option 1 and option2 are working but option 3 is not, I do not know why and how to fix it.
I am trying to do array comparison with option 3

Comment: Could you apply some formatting? It's difficult/irritating to read as it is.

Comment: Format your question and tell us what error its giving you.  Provide full queries as well, small snippets make it more difficult to follow.

Comment: I found my problem;
option 3 was not working because it was comparing bigint[] with integer[]. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not working because it was comparing `bigint[]` with `integer[]`.